# Short VHDL for loop code i dont understand

Tags: vhdl

I do understand how to convert a binary number into a decimal number but the following code thats supposed to do that doesnt make sense. I mean lets sat we have a binary number 10, then v(i) would be 0, so result stays 0. Upon the next iteration v(i) will be 1 so result will be 0 + 1 . The loop stops and the function will return the value of result which is 1 and not 2 which is the value of the binary number put into the function. Could someone tell me why I am wrong? This code comes with a university assignment so it should be correct. Thanks. :)

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- convert std_logic vector v to natural
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

FUNCTION s2n(v: std_logic_vector)
RETURN natural IS
VARIABLE result: natural := 0;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN v'range LOOP
            result := result * 2;
            IF v(i) = '1' THEN
                    result := result + 1;
            END IF;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN result;
END s2n;
```

Comment: Have you considered that the range of your `std_logic_vector` can be increasing `(0 to 7)` or decreasing `(7 downto 0)`? Usually binary numbers are represented using decreasing indices, with the most significant bit to the left.

Comment: OH i cant believe i didnt see that v(1) is the first digit to the left : )

Comment: @Philippe: I'd say the constant factor is that the left-most digit is the most significant.  Big-endian processors like PowerPC variants (and Microblaze before it became little endian aware) have D0 as the msb of the databus doing D(0:31)

Comment: "This code comes with a university assignment so it should be correct"---you may want to reconsider that!

Answer (score 1):

The `'range` loop works from left to right.  The convention is for the most-significant bit to be on the left

By decoding that first, the `*2` operation gets run most times on the MSB as you'd expect.

(BTW, if you want the range to go the other way for some reason, you can use the `'reverse_range` attribute)